# Why does "23 Dogs" get parsed to 23 november 2015 in pry, but "3 Dogs" gives a parser error?

Tags: ruby, date, parsing, pry

I found the below code snippet on Twitter (check post history for source).

```
[5] pry(main)> Date.parse('3 Dogs')
ArgumentError: invalid date
[6] pry(main)> Date.parse('23 Dogs')
=> Mon, 23 Nov 2015
```

Is this just an easter egg in pry? If so, why this particular date and result? If it's not an easter egg, why does `23 Dogs` parse to a date, but `3 Dogs`doesn't parse?

Comment: *Is this just an easter egg in pry?*  Yes, only pry would produce that result.  If you ran that code in a ruby program, or in irb, Date.parse() would produce: "Hello world" for that data.  What do you get for `Date.parse('23')` and `Date.parse('3')`?

Comment: Actually, you should get `NameError: uninitialized constant Date` in both cases.

Comment: @7stud I don't know, I don't have pry installed. If only pry gives that result, is that because it was hardcoded like that, or because pry has a different Date parser? And why does it give this result?

Comment: Your question contains a lot of extraneous information. In future please pare it down to essentials. Also, it's best to avoid links that can be broken.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I found the first image, added a source, transcribed it to copyable code, then asked my questions: does this only happen in pry? and why does this happen? I then included another image in reply to 7stud's comment to show what other parameters give and added the source for that. I'm not sure what exactly you consider "extraneous information". The links are to provide the source for the image to comply with copyright rules.

Comment: 1. The pic at the top is repeated. 2. To read the Tweets we must wade through comments such as "that’s as crazy as some JS, that. Wat." and  "your twitter pic juxtaposed with that screenshot is absolutely perfect". 3. "Easter Egg"? Cute is OK as long as it's understandable. 4. The Tweets are irrelevant. If you'd gathered that information from books and blogs, would you cite each source? After confirming comments in the Tweets, just summarized what you've observed, without reference to sources. 4. I have no idea what "Dating Dogs" refers to. (Maybe it's explain in the second Twitter thread.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'll try to edit it tomorrow without ruining the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I edited to account for point 1, 2, 4 and 5. "Easter Egg" is a well-known term in the IT-sector and the internet which indicates something which has been added as an in-joke or a cultural reference. I can't remove this from the question without invalidating part of the below answers.

Comment: That's much better, imo, but the important thing is that it was and is a very good question. I hope you get a definitive answer, as I too would like to know what's going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Pry. If you examine the doc for [Date::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) you'll see, "If the optional second argument [`comp`] is true [the default] and the detected year is in the range “00” to “99”, considers the year a 2-digit form and makes it full.".

This is admittedly odd. It detects `"23"` to be in the range `"00".."30"` (but not `"3"` or any of `"0".."9"`), so it concludes it's a date. Note that any value in the range `"31".."99"` raises an exception as well. I expect the `"30"` is the high end of the range because it is currently November and November hath 30 days. It then seems to discard that information and use the current year and month, and assume the day is `"23"` (or raise an exception if, say, `"31"` had been entered). Can anyone explain the details of what's going on?

Comment: I get that they parse 23 to 23, but why does "Dogs" get parsed to "november 2015"? And why does 23 get parsed as a valid date, but 3 doesn't?

Comment: Something to remember about `Date.parse()` is that it discards unparseable data and parses whatever's left. The 'Dogs' has no effect on the result. You get the same if you try `Date.parse('23')` or `Date.parse('23 cats')` or `Date.parse('23 Obamas')`.

Comment: For a further example:
    `irb(main):006:0> Date.parse('On 23 March I got 3 new Dogs')`
    `==> #<Date: 2015-03-23 ((2457105j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`
The only thing in that example that it parsed was "23 March"

Comment: @KenB, yes, but we still need to understand (to be able to sleep at night) why Ruby seems to be saying `"23"` is the year! [brief pause] `"23"` is the day!".

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm not understanding... in all the examples I've seen, both in this Q/A and in my terminal, '23' *is* interpreted as the day. The original example was `Date.parse('23 Dogs') => Mon, 23 Nov 2015`. Or do you mean that the Ruby docs say it *should* be reading it as the year? Your testing seems to demonstrate that this isn't the case, since e.g. it breaks above 30.

Comment: @KenB, OK, "Dogs" is not relevant. You might think think that `9` should parse as the day, but it raises an exception. It's not that `9`it could be the day or the month (unlike `23`), since `10`, `11` and `12` parse just fine (the first to `2015-11-10`. I just don't understand how `parse` works. Consider: `Date.parse '9-18' => 2015-11-18`, `Date.parse '9-18-2015' => invalid date`.  In my mind this bolsters the case for using [Date::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_strptime) whenever possible.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Moral of this story is that, yeah, definitely use strptime whenever you can. As for the specific examples you gave: across the board, it appears that Date.parse follows a few rules: 1. it only looks for 2-digit and 4-digit numbers, thus in '9-18' it ignores the '9'; 2. it assumes one 2-digit num is a day, thus plugging '18' into the current month and year; 3. it can't handle two nums, only 1 or 3, which (with 1.) is why '9-18-2015' fails, since it only sees '18-2015' and doesn't know how to parse that

Comment: @KenB. Some more data points (all beginning `Date.parse`): `"3 18"`
and `"3-18" => 2015-11-18`, but `"3/18" => 2015-03-18` and `3/9"
 => 2015-03-09`. `"3/9 23" => 2003-09-23`, `"23 3/9"
 => 2015-03-09`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Wow, looks like '/' triggers a different set of rules that allows for single-digit nums. Super weird. So again, all the more evidence for preferring strptime whenever you possibly can

Answer (score 3):

So it's got nothing to do with pry. I can reproduce your report in ruby 2.2.2 in ruby code that does not load pry at all.

So why the heck is Date.parse willing to parse "23 dogs" and come up with something? I have no idea. I'd say it's some idiosyncracy or even bug in Date's parsing; it attempts to parse all manner of things, but this leads to some odd edge cases.

For more predictable parsing of dates in known fixed formats, use [Date#strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) instead. For more sophisticated parsing of natural language dates in unpredictable formats, use the [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/) gem.

Personally, I never use straight `Date.parse`, because it's kind of unpredictable, using one of those two methods instead. (Or specific format parsing methods like `Date.iso8601`).

I tried to look at the MRI code for `Date.parse` because I was curious if I could figure out what it was doing. But quickly got lost in C code I wasn't competent to understand or follow, and had to give up.

Interestingly, this DOES reproduce in JRuby 1.7.10 too (I haven't installed jruby 9x yet).  "23 dogs" parses to the same thing, "3 dogs" raises. Hm, perhaps the JRuby Java code will be more intelligible to some of us than MRI's C code. But I haven't had time to try to work through/debug just what Date#parse in JRuby is doing. The meat of it *maybe* begins [here](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/3c164ca93d1e60373fd5f2c7f1895915fb8c577e/lib/ruby/stdlib/date/format.rb#L834), although I might not have found the correct place for current version implementation.  You can see that it tries parsing the date according to a number of different formats in sequence, stopping when it succesfully parses according to some format. We can guess there's SOME weird format in that list that somehow succesfuly parses "23 dogs" but not "3 dogs".  It's probalby not an easter egg or intentional at all; it's just a weird side effect of trying to parse a date by just trying to guess what format it is in and trying various formats in sequence, not a very sophisticated algorithm.

**update** Okay, in at least the jruby code I was looking at (which might not be the current implementation, but is some implementation)

- Eventually, after trying other potential parses which fail, it tries `Date._parse_ddd` -- for both inputs.
- `Date._parse_ddd("23 dogs", e)` returns `true`, and fills the Date::Parse::Bag with an `mday` component, but  `Date._parse_ddd("3 dogs", e)` returns false and does not fill the `Bag`. So everything else follows from here.
- If we look at the [Date._parse_ddd](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/3c164ca93d1e60373fd5f2c7f1895915fb8c577e/lib/ruby/stdlib/date/format.rb#L696) implementation... there's some monster regexes and weird logic. Probably copied from MRI to be consistent with MRI, or otherwise made consistent with MRI behavior.
- I don't feel like debugging further. You can if you want. The JRuby implementation, as you can see, is actually written in ruby, not even in Java.

You or I or someone could try to debug further (perhaps even with an interactive debugger on JRuby stdlib implementation) to figure out *exactly* what's going on. But I'm confident the answer is just basically "it's a weird side effect of Date.parse not really knowing what format it's input is in, but just trying a bunch of things, using a not very sophisticated algorithm, sometimes weird things happen"

**more update**: Note that `Date.parse("03 dogs")` does parse instead of raising. So two numerals it decides are parseable, one it does not. But of course `Date.parse("3 May")` works fine. It's not that `Date.parse` requires two digit dates, it's just that it's trying a whole bunch of different ways of parsing it, and an actual good date will be caught correctly, but a bad date might be caught by one of the ways that thought it seemed good enough, but in this case was wrong.

**more thoughts** So it's not intentional that it parses like that. It's a byproduct of heuristic rules meant to catch other dates. Since the code isn't commented we can't say exactly what sorts of dates what parts were meant to catch. It's sort of a bunch of cobbled together stuff to try and catch dates in a variety of formats, including international formats.

You could look at the tests to see all the kinds of dates it's meant to catch. Or you could try to go through the code to understand exactly which lines result in the behavior you are seeing. The code is confusing -- especially the C code in MRI, to most of us. The pure ruby code in JRuby is more readable of course to we rubyists. Since it's confusing and time-consuming to go through the code, with little benefit (who cares?), you probably aren't going to get anyone else to do this for you.

Comment: I had a look at the C source as well, and got no further. We need someone familiar with it to step through and tell us what's happening.

Comment: What I've noticed is that because of the space between `23` and `Dogs`, the second capture group is actually 3 characters long, not 2. I'm not sure how this changes things. Could you try doing Date.parse("23dogs") and see what response you get then?

Comment: Yes, in MRI, "23dogs" returns the same date object as does "23 Dogs".